# Git post-receive hook error on server

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to have a git 'post-receive' on my server. I am using the following code on the hook file:

```
#!/bin/bash
#CONFIG
LIVE="/home/ubuntu/public_html/testing"

read oldrev newrev refname
if [ $refname = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
  echo "===== DEPLOYING TO LIVE SITE ====="
  unset GIT_DIR  
  cd $LIVE
 # ssh-agent $BASH
 # ssh-add /home/ubuntu/.ssh/ubuntu
  git pull --verbose origin  master || echo "git-pull: returned error code"     
  echo "===== DONE ====="
fi
```

It is showing the following error mesasge whenever I am trying to push something from my local pc to server:

```
===== DEPLOYING TO LIVE SITE =====
remote: error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
remote: 
remote: git-pull: returned error code
remote: ===== DONE =====
```

Can anyone please help what can be the issue?

Just to confirm, I have tried with the same user credential to run the command via ssh terminal and it worked fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What protocol are you using for your push/fetch/pull operations (i.e. are you running a `git-daemon` or is everything `ssh+git://<something>`). If you're using `git-daemon`, is the user id on the daemon (and thus what is running your hook) capable of reading/writing to your "live" repository?

Comment: I am using ssh with public key authentication. Isn't it ok? Also, the user I am pushing with, share the same private key on server and on my local pc. Isn't it ok? Or do you suggest to do it in some other way? Thanks.

Comment: Using ssh is fine... The scenario I mentioned above using `git-daemon` is one I had run into in the past, so I thought it was one possible explanation for what you're seeing, but it sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: I just want to say thanks. Your script is exactly what I was looking for. I am moving from WAMP to a VM running linux so I can 'get a taste for web administration' and to make editing my code easier, I set up bare git repo. I had been looking for almost 2 days when I came across your code. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I did able to solve it by changing the ownership of the directory(/home/ubuntu/public_html/testing) to the user who is commiting/running hook.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've received error messages about permissions and FETCH_HEAD, it's because I've accidentally made a pull as root whilst tinkering around with something, which creates files in the .git directory owned by root, which my normal ssh user can't overwrite.

I usually run `ls -laR .git | grep root` (I'm sure there's a better way, I'm no sysadmin) to check if there are any files owned by root. Simply chown'ing them back allows me to carry on as normal.

Comment: Hi, I have checked and the files are owned by proper user, so no problem from that part.

Comment: I did able to solve it by changing the ownership to the user 'git' (in which user, gitolite is being installed with). However, now getting another issue. scripts are being updated though, its not being executed on webserver/apache. Any idea what might be the issue?